# How can you avoid mice in your hospital?

Tags: theme-hospital

What affects when mouse holes start spawning in your hospital? Is it the amount of garbage or something similar? I currently have a quite clean hospital, but still the mice start showing up.

Comment: I havent heard of this game in soooooo long....

Answer (score 9):

There is a lot of wild speculation about this on the internet.

From my experience, I believe the mice always appear regardless of what you do, but they have no effect on anything (patients don't complain, health inspectors doesn't care etc.).

The only thing you can do it kill them with your cursor, which creates mess that has to be cleaned up and you can get an end-of-year trophy if you kill lots of them.

Some people claim that mice create epidemics, others that you can keep their levels low by keeping your hospital warm and/or placing items (like drinks machines) in front of their holes. I don't think that's true...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can.

However, to add to vesan's information, you can also get rid of mouse holes by putting a bench in front of the hole and then removing it.

Comment: Your not actually adding any information, unfortunetly. Vesan already covers that.

Comment: @Timelord64 He says some people claim you can keep levels low by placing things in front of their holes. I'm offering the addition that the game doesn't "cover" the hole, it removes it. You can place a bench there and then remove the bench, and the hole is gone, so your map wont be littered with unsightly and annoying holes.

Comment: We have comments for something so trivial..